# How to disable external nameservers in CPANEL/WHM?

Tags: cpanel, whm

I have a domain with nameservers that point to my server and i was replaceing the nameservers with external nameservers that forward the www to my server. I need to allow only domains that use my nameservers to acces my server.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, You will have to disable " Allow Remote Domains" in your Tweak Settings. Once you disable it, You can add new domain on your server which is NOT using your server nameserver.